# How to set default selected values in multiselect with ngModel in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-ngmodel, angular2-ngmodel, ngmodel

How to set default selected values in multiselect. I get `current_options` and `all_options` from database and I want to update `current_options` and send new values do database again.

Updating database works but when I refresh page none of options are selected.

```
current_options = [{id:1, name:'name1'}];                    #from database
all_options = [{id:1, name:'name1'},{id:2, name:'name2'}];   #from database
```

My template:

```
<select multiple name="type" [(ngModel)]="current_options">
    <option  *ngFor="let option of all_options" [ngValue] = "option">
        {{option.name}}
    </option>
</select>`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want create multiple select and option with ngModel  and set default value and two way bind its working code

```
<div  *ngFor="let options of optionsArray; let in = index">
 <br>
 <select [(ngModel)]="res[in]" >
 <option  [ngValue]="option" *ngFor="let option of options.options; let i =index">


{{option}}
</option>
</select>
 {{res[in]}}
</div>
{{res}}

export class ExComponent implements OnInit {
public res=[];
 public optionsArray = [
   {id: 1, text: 'Sentence 1', options:['kapil','vinay']},
   {id: 2, text: 'Sentence 2', options:['mukesh','anil']},
   {id: 3, text: 'Sentence 3', options:['viky','kd']},
  {id: 4, text: 'Sentence 4', options:['alok','gorva']},
]
ngOnInit() 
{
this.optionsArray.forEach(data=>{
 this.res.push(data.options[0]);
})
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You should be using an array of selected items

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedElement" multiple>
     <option *ngFor="let type of types" [ngValue]="type"> {{type.Name}}</option>
</select>
```

My selected item will be as below

```
selectedElement:any= [
                {id:1,Name:'abc'},
                {id:2,Name:'abdfsdgsc'}];
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/s2qtweu6qQclT54NIjRi?p=preview)**

Answer (score 5):

If you will pass the values as an id array to ngModel

```
let idArrary = ["1"];

<select multiple name="type" [(ngModel)]="idArrary">
    <option  *ngFor="let option of all_options" [ngValue] = "option">
        {{option.name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

`

Answer (score 2):

`current_options = [all_options[0]]`
To initialize the default value of your input.

Current_options need to be initialize with an array containing the same objects present in all_options.

I forked the [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/qYQdvzB2N4GQEi7OQzVI?p=preview) from another answer to illustrate it.

Keep in mind that :

```
{id:1, name:'name1'} !== {id:1, name:'name1'}
```

**Edit:**

Assuming current_options is already containing some value you are receiving from your server:

```
current_options = current_options.map((current_option) => {
   return all_options.find((all_option) => current_option.id === all_option.id);
})
```

Or probably more performant:

```
for (let i in all_options) { 
   for (let j in current_options) { 
      if (all_options[i].id === current_options[j].id ) { 
         current_options[j] = all_options[i]; 
      } 
   } 
}
```

**Edit:**
According to angular [documentation](https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectMultipleControlValueAccessor) you can use a compare with function to specify how to assume two objects are equal.

```
<select multiple [compareWith]="compareFn" ...>
</select>

compareFn(c1: Category, c2: Category): boolean {
  return c1 && c2 ? c1.id === c2.id : c1 === c2;
}
```

Comment: What is `optionFromDatabase`? I can use only `current_options` and `all_options`

Comment: You said your current_options was initialised  by database.

Comment: `current_options` is a part of bigger object I want to display `current_options` as selected items in select field, eventually change selected items and send object to database.

Comment: I edited my answer, guess i forgot about the multiple part of the select.

Comment: So, to  initialize the default values (if current_options I get from database I should do this:
`for (let i in all_options) {
      for (let j in current_options) {
        if (this.all_options[i].id === current_options[j].id ) {
           current_options.push(this.all_options[i]);
        }
      }
    }`
?

Comment: `for (let i in all_options) { for (let j in current_options) { if (this.all_options[i].id === current_options[j].id ) { current_options[j] = this.all_options[i]; } } }`
I'll put a smoother solution into my post.

Comment: Nubinub, your solution works well, but I have to set current_options in every component. I'd like to subscribe current_options in model like that: `for (let cat of obj.cat) {
        this.category.push(new Category(at));
      }` and use it: `<select multiple name="type" [(ngModel)]="obj.category">` but this code not work (options are not selected) although model has the same type `Category[]` as all_options type (also `Category[]`). Do you now why it doesn't work?

Comment: `cat !== new Category(cat)`

Comment: @pelcomppl I edited my answer with a feture i just discovered in angular documentation.